# compiler non running apacite package on SAGE Latex template

Tags: apacite

#### The problem

I am using a SAGE Latex template, which loads the following packages:

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}

\usepackage{moreverb,url}

\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
```

Then I am loading some additional packages including apacite:

```
% Additional packages
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{subfig}
% \usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

Whenever apacite is included, I get the error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
 \st@rtbibchapter
```

#### What I have tried

1. I have tried using the `article` class, but that works fine with the apacite package. I think the problem is the `sagej` class.
2. If I run the code commenting out the apacite in the `sagej` class, I get a reference page because of the `sageh` option, but the formatting is all wrong:

[image]:

3. I have tried using the `sageapa` option as suggested [here](https://us.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/latex_frequently_asked_questions_10312017_.pdf) instead of `sageh`, but I don't get any references in the reference page.

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageapa,times]{sagej}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using *both* the `sageapa` option and loading the apacite package:

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageapa,times]{sagej}
(...)
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```